# compare one column from one table that like column another table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

i have 2 table in mysql.
for example: first table is A and second table is B.
one column of A table has value 4419 (column type is bigint)
one column of B table has value a:4:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:4:"4419";i:2;s:4:"4421";} (column type is longtext)
i want to show records from a table that exist in column of b value.
column b has a lot of character and some character is same with column a table,
my query is some thing like this query

```
select * from `a`,`b` where `a`.column like  '%'+`b`.`column` + '%'
```

i change a and b  table like below

```
select * from `a`,`b` where `b`.column like  '%'+`a`.`column` + '%'
```

my query has not error and show empty record and when i use 'not LIKE' in my query. it return some value that means  my syntax is true.
how can i write my query?
Thank you in advance for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are using `+` with the intention of concatenating strings.  And that is not how MySQL works.  Use the `CONCAT()` function:

```
select *
from `a` join
     `b`
     on `b`.column like  concat('%', `a`.`column`, '%');
```

Note that this puts the logic in an `on` clause because the intent appears to be to join the tables using this logic.